# DateTimePicker Not Working in a partial view

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

DateTimePicker not working.I am trying to use this bootstrap and jquery sources from external resources(no links or scripts added below are in my solution)!

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>  
   <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script> 

     <div style="display:inline;">
             <span id="PickUpDate" class="locationdetail-text-input">
                <input data-format="MM-dd-yyyy" type="text" style="width:110px; height:20px;" />
                <span class="add-on">
                  <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon- calendar"></i>
                </span>
              </span>
              <span id="PickUpTime" class="locationdetail-text-input">
                <input data-format="hh:mm" type="text"  style="width:110px; height:20px;" />
                <span class="add-on">
                      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
                </span>
              </span>
      </div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PickUpDate').datetimepicker({ pickTime: false });

        $('#PickUpTime').datetimepicker({ pickDate: false });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in Console?

Comment: is your script on the partial?

Answer (score 2):

If this is your partial code then you need to remove all of the script off of it.  Put the references that you need on the main page.  When the partial is added to the page it will then have access to those references you will then just need to instantiate the date picker.  Put your calls in a function

```
function SetUpPickers(){
   $('#PickUpDate').datetimepicker({ pickTime: false });

    $('#PickUpTime').datetimepicker({ pickDate: false }); 
}
```

then call this function after you load the partial.  if you load the partial in an ajax call something like

```
.success(data){
    $('.ContentDiv').html(data);
    SetUpPickers();
}
```